# How can I make the roadmap scroll effect in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, scroll, effect

I'd love to make the effect like image.

[image]

When I scroll down the roadmap, the aircraft will move like image.

I tried to find the same and similar effect using react, but couldn't find it.

If you know about this and have reference links for this, could you gimme and guide me?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried making the airplane `position: sticky` ?

Comment: @wouch can you put the reference links?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky_positioning